# routes from api.php not found after copying htacess on root

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-8

I can access routes that is in /myproject/routes/web.php but I can't access routes in /myproject/routes/api.php

I installed laravel version 8 on xampp and copy htaccess to root folder of my project then rename server.php to index.php so I can call my project in web like http://localhost/myproject.

all of my assets on /myproject/public/template/ is accessible too

here is my .htaccess file

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
    <IfModule mod_negotiation.c>
        Options -MultiViews -Indexes
    </IfModule>

    RewriteEngine On
    
    # Handle Authorization Header
    RewriteCond %{HTTP:Authorization} .
    RewriteRule .* - [E=HTTP_AUTHORIZATION:%{HTTP:Authorization}]

    # Redirect Trailing Slashes If Not A Folder...
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} (.+)/$
    RewriteRule ^ %1 [L,R=301]

    # Send Requests To Front Controller...
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
    RewriteRule ^ index.php [L]
</IfModule>
```

Comment: Which api you trying to call can you give that route name ,So it would be better?

Answer (score 1):

make sure that the .htaccess file is in the root directory of your Laravel application.

make sure that the RewriteBase is set correctly. It should point to the root directory of your Laravel application. For example, if your Laravel application is installed in a subdirectory called myapp, you would set the RewriteBase like this:

```
RewriteBase /myapp/
```

and you can try clearing the cache

```
php artisan cache:clear
php artisan route:cache
```

hopefully that is help you